# How do you mock a Sealed class?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic, tdd, mocking

[Mocking sealed classes](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20mock%20sealed%20class) can be quite a pain.  I currently favor an [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to handle this, but something about just keeps feels weird.

**So, What is the best way you mock sealed classes?**

*Java answers are more than welcome*.  In fact, I would anticipate that the Java community has been dealing with this longer and has a great deal to offer.

But here are some of the .NET opinions:

- [Why Duck Typing Matters for C#
  Develoepers](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/19/why-duck-typing-matters-to-c-developers.aspx)
- [Creating wrappers
  for sealed and other types for
  mocking](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2008/07/22/Creating-wrappers-for-sealed-and-other-types-for-mocking.aspx)
- [Unit tests for WCF (and Moq)](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/05/16/unit-tests-for-wcf.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is that objects that I need to mock should have a common interface too. I think this is right design-wise and makes tests a lot easier (and is usually what you get if you do TDD). More about this can be read in the Google Testing Blog [latest post](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html) (See point 9).

Also, I've been working mainly in Java in the past 4 years and I can say that I can count on one hand the number of times I've created a final (sealed) class. Another rule here is I should always have a good reason to seal a class, as opposed to sealing it by default.

Comment: I would argue that you should have a good reason *not* to seal a class. Leaving a class open means you need to think about how it will be used by inheritors, which opens up a floodgate of decisions about all the code in the class (virtuality, protected properties or private member variables, etc.) It is *hard* to properly design a class for inheritance. You shouldn't be able to extend a class just for extension's sake; derivation should mean something specific to the problem being modeled. Otherwise, favor composition instead.

Comment: Bryan - so how would you mock a sealed class then?  I agree with you from a theoretical standpoint, but if you write something dependent on your sealed class then your tests depend on the sealed class as well.

Comment: @abyx: Unfortunately, it is not always the developer's choice whether a class is sealed or not. Take, e.g., System.Web.HttpServerUtility in ASP.NET...

Comment: @BryanWatts I disagree strongly with this.  Sealing a class simply denies coders the opportunity to inherit the class.  They might find extending it useful in a way you haven't foreseen.  You don't need to worry about them somehow screwing things up; it's (probably) not your responsibility.  I'd actually do away with the `sealed` keyword.

Comment: @Jez: If I hadn't considered extension when writing the class, what reason is there to trust it?

Comment: Strongly agree with @Jez.

Happy to see the official guideline shares the same opinion: "DO NOT seal classes without having a good reason to do so. Sealing a class because you cannot think of an extensibility scenario is not a good reason." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/sealing)

To protect methods from being misused by subclass, just leave them private. Isn't it enough?

Comment: @Beepbeep if you have control over the sealed class yourself, you can specify an interface that this sealed class implements and you can mock this interface. If you don't control the class that is sealed (e.g. it's from a library), you might want to create an adapter that delegates functionality from the sealed class. Not only will you be able to mock this adapter (or its interface), but it will also be easier to switch to a different library, if needed.

Comment: Whether or not you want to seal every class has to some extent a relation with whether or not you want to add a disclaimer to your project. 
If there is a strict requirement for the (usually proprietary) code to do a certain number of things and nothing more (with eye for security and preventing the use of  weird machines), then it is fine to seal whenever possible. 
If the code is an (open source) library for general use with only a loose specification for what it is supposed to do, then don't seal all classes. 
And then there is everything in the middle that you can debate over.

Answer (score 21):

For .NET, you could use something like [TypeMock](https://www.typemock.com/), which uses the profiling API and allows you to hook into calls to nearly anything.

Comment: +1. Use the right tools. Don't let tools dictate you how you should do things. APIs are for people, not for tools - design them as such. Use DI and interfaces and full decoupling where it makes sense, not just because you need it for testing tools.

Comment: Pavel - the problem is that the "Right" way in .NET usually leads you down a path of 'Use TypeMock to test'.  Following a path where there is only one testing tool available doesn't seem great either.

Comment: Some people might not like paying $80 a month for a test framework.

Comment: I think Moles allows you to work with sealed classes - and if you have a MSDN subscription, it's free.

Comment: AFAIK one of the main problems with these frameworks which can mock sealed classes, statics, etc. is performance. Personally I prefer to create an interface and use that in my production code, with an inheriting proxy object injected during production and a mock injected during testing.

Answer (score 14):

I believe that [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/), from Microsoft Research, allows you to do that. From the Moles page:

> Moles may be used to detour any .NET
> method, including non-virtual/static
> methods in sealed types.

**UPDATE:** there is a new framework called "Fakes" in the upcoming VS 11 release that is designed to replace Moles:

> The [Fakes Framework in Visual Studio 11](http://aka.ms/vs11-fakes) is the next generation of Moles & Stubs, and will eventually replace it. Fakes is different from Moles, however, so moving from Moles to Fakes will require some modifications to your code. A guide for this migration will be available at a later date.
>
> **Requirements**: Visual Studio 11 Ultimate, .NET 4.5

Answer (score 7):

The problem with TypeMock is that it excuses bad design. Now, I know that it is often *someone else's* bad design that it's hiding, but permitting it into your development process can lead very easily to permitting your own bad designs.

I think if you're going to use a mocking framework, you should use a traditional one (like Moq) and create an isolation layer around the unmockable thing, and mock the isolation layer instead.

Comment: Not slapping interfaces on everything in sight just because you need them because of deficiencies of your testing tools is not bad design. In fact, quite the opposite - it's _sane_ design that is about design, not about conforming to your tools. I swear, sometimes I think that TDD as it's often dogmatically practiced should really be called "tools-driven design". Also see http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2008/01/17/is-typemock-too-powerful-will-it-kill-design-for-testability.aspx

Comment: Pavel - do you have another tool other than TypeMock that can provide this type of testing?  Testing classes built with sane designs (e.g. using static methods, new calls in code, limiting interfaces to where multiple implementations are needed, etc) are often next to impossible to test.

Comment: I agree with Brad here.  Creating a mock object implies you are testing that type's public behavior.  That is, you are specifically saying, "I need the public API of this object to behave in a certain way."  This behavior is *independent* of however said API is implemented.  This means you have an already-defined (though implicit) abstraction which needs to behave a certain way.  In a static type system, this must be made explicit by creating an abstract type.

Answer (score 7):

I came across this problem recently and after reading / searching web, seems like there is no easy way around except to use another tool as mentioned above.
Or crude of handling things as I did:

- Create instance of sealed class without getting constructor called.
- `System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(instanceType)`;
- Assign values to your properties / fields via reflection
- `YourObject.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").SetValue(dto, newValue, null);`
- `YourObject.GetType().GetField("FieldName").SetValue(dto, newValue);`

Comment: This is the only solution that makes sense and works for mocking internal Microsoft stuff without adding any extra libraries like Fakes - thank you!

Comment: And is three lines of code and free.

Answer (score 3):

I almost always avoid having dependencies on external classes deep within my code.  Instead, I'd much rather use an adapter/bridge to talk to them.  That way, I'm dealing with my semantics, and the pain of translating is isolated in one class.

It also makes it easier to switch my dependencies in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I generally take the route of creating an interface and adaptor/proxy class to facilitate mocking of the sealed type.  However, I've also experimented with skipping creation of the interface and making the proxy type non-sealed with virtual methods.  This worked well when the proxy is really a natural base class that encapsulates and users part of the sealed class.

When dealing with code that required this adaptation, I got tired of performing the same actions to create the interface and proxy type so I implemented a library to automate the task.

The code is somewhat more sophisticated than the sample given in the article you reference, as it produces an assembly (instead of source code), allows for code generation to be performed on any type, and doesn't require as much configuration.

For more information, please refer to [this page](http://jolt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Jolt.Testing.CodeGeneration.Proxy&referringTitle=Jolt.Testing).

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly reasonable to mock a sealed class because many framework classes are sealed.

In my case I'm trying to mock .Net's MessageQueue class so that I can TDD my graceful exception handling logic.

If anyone has ideas on how to overcome Moq's error regarding "Invalid setup on a non-overridable member", please let me know.

code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        Queue<Message> messages = new Queue<Message>();
        Action<Message> sendDelegate = msg => messages.Enqueue(msg);
        Func<TimeSpan, MessageQueueTransaction, Message> receiveDelegate =
            (v1, v2) =>
            {
                throw new Exception("Test Exception to simulate a failed queue read.");
            };

        MessageQueue mockQueue = QueueMonitorHelper.MockQueue(sendDelegate, receiveDelegate).Object;
    }
    public static Mock<MessageQueue> MockQueue
                (Action<Message> sendDelegate, Func<TimeSpan, MessageQueueTransaction, Message> receiveDelegate)
    {
        Mock<MessageQueue> mockQueue = new Mock<MessageQueue>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        Expression<Action<MessageQueue>> sendMock = (msmq) => msmq.Send(It.IsAny<Message>()); //message => messages.Enqueue(message);
        mockQueue.Setup(sendMock).Callback<Message>(sendDelegate);

        Expression<Func<MessageQueue, Message>> receiveMock = (msmq) => msmq.Receive(It.IsAny<TimeSpan>(), It.IsAny<MessageQueueTransaction>());
        mockQueue.Setup(receiveMock).Returns<TimeSpan, MessageQueueTransaction>(receiveDelegate);

        return mockQueue;
    }
```

Comment: I have found a solution and posted here: http://www.dotnetmonkey.net/post/Hard-to-Moq.aspx

Comment: too bad that page is dead

Comment: thanks for the solution! the page is still dead though

Comment: You can  find the page on wayback machine; however, don't waste your time. The post has been updated by the author saying that it didn't actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's currently only available in beta release, I think it's worthwhile keeping in mind the [shim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) feature of the new [Fakes framework](http://aka.ms/vs11-fakes) (part of the [Visual Studio 11](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us) Beta release).

> Shim types provide a mechanism to detour any .NET method to a user defined delegate. Shim types are code-generated by the Fakes generator, and they use delegates, which we call shim types, to specify the new method implementations. Under the hood, shim types use callbacks that were injected at runtime in the method MSIL bodies.

Personally, I was looking at using this to mock the methods on sealed framework classes such as DrawingContext.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to implement a sealed class from an interface... and mock the interface instead?

Something in me feels that having sealed classes is wrong in the first place, but that's just me :)

Comment: I think sealed classes are great ... the problem is testing.  It stinks that we have to change our entire design because of limitations in testing .NET projects.  In many cases D.I. is simply a way to get around the fact that static classes/methods are hard to test.