# How can I mock an OracleConnection and OracleCommand?

Tags: c#, oracle, unit-testing, moq

For my tests I need to mock out the data client, in my case they are Oracle.

I have created my data access layer to allow this to be passed in:

```
public static Int32? GetUserRoleId(string userName, OracleConnection cn, OracleCommand cmd)
```

I am using Moq, though I can switch to another framework if needed, and when I go to create the Mock objects like this:

```
Mock<OracleConnection> mockOracleConnection = new Mock<OracleConnection>();
Mock<OracleCommand> mockOracleCommand = new Mock<OracleCommand>();
```

I get this error:

> Failure: System.ArgumentException : Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.

**Conclusion:**
This was more simple than I thought! Just mock the DAL layer function like this:

```
mockDao.Setup(a => a.GetUserRoleId(userName, It.IsAny<OracleConnection>(), It.IsAny<OracleCommand>())).Returns(1);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make changes to use IDbConnection and IDbCommand (use interfaces and have a factory to provide the real objects in main code and mock objects in test - normally using Dependency Injection)

Moq can only mock Interfaces and virtual methods.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mock a sealed class: you can look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484/how-do-you-mock-a-sealed-class).

BTW: As @Aliostad [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728412/how-can-i-mock-an-oracleconnection-and-oraclecommand/3728493#3728493), such framework - most mock frameworks I've seen too - can mock only Interfaces/Abstract classes.