# Can I Override a property of a class I cannot inherit from?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

I want to unit test a class that reads the power information.
I have a private readonly variable which i assign a value from System.Windows.SystemInformation.PowerStatus and i can use reflection to change this no problem but...

System.Windows.PowerStatus does not have a public constructor and won't let me inherit from it to derive a testPowerStatus class i can use with my tests.

I want to be able to override the getter for BatteryLifePercent and BatteryLifeRemaining property so i can test that the correct behavior happens when these are certain values.

Is there anyway i can do this? or is this impossible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484/how-do-you-mock-a-sealed-class

Comment: take a look at the composition design pattern too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: thank you both for your answers. I am creating a wrapper for the sealed class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" way to do this is to create an abstraction layer. You should create a IPowerInfoProvider interface, and then create a stub implementing the interface for tests, and another implementation providing real power info.

Your BL should only know about the IPowerInfoProvider interface.

Comment: I have created an interface then a class that implements that and returns the systeminformation and a class that returns mock information. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You dont actually need to test a routine which assigns a value from System.Windows.SystemInformation.PowerStatus to a private variable, try to extract the logic you ned to test in a separate routine, for example a methode which has a number as a parameter which simulates the relivant information.

Take a look at the members the [PowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus.aspx) exposes, they are all either int, float or enums try to provide these as parameters to your units which will then be easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather make an interface IPowerStatus having the properties and methods you need. Than I would create wrapper class for `System.Windows.PowerStatus` implementing IPowerStatus and recaling methods and getters/setters on keeped object. And for unit tests you can use some mock implementing your IPowerStatus.