# How to Mock Sealed class with RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, tdd, rhino-mocks

I want to write tests for the code below.  For this I want to inject in a mocked HttpContext using RhinoMocks.

HttpContext is sealed though.

How should I handle this?

Thanks

```
    public PaxiumPrincipal CreatePrincipalFromCookie(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie == null)
        {
            return null;
        };

        var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        if (authTicket == null)
        {
            return null;
        };

        var userPrincipal = new PaxiumPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), null);

        return userPrincipal;
    }
```

Comment: You can't. Write an adapter for HttpContext and mock it instead

Comment: Here's a more general version of your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484/how-do-you-mock-a-sealed-class)

Comment: Igor - by Adapter you mean one of these?  http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern

Comment: Yes, I mean Adapter pattern.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Since someone marked this as a duplicate question, does this mean it cannot be answered and I therefore do not need to nominate an accepted answer?

Comment: @DaveAmour Once a question is closed (in this case because it's a duplicate), no new answers can be added.  If there had already been an answer posted, then you could mark it as the accepted answer if you wanted to, however as there aren't any answers currently on this question that isn't an option.

Comment: Ok thanks, Its very strict on this site!