# How to Mock NamespaceManager Class Methods Using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN#microsoft_servicebus_namespacemanager

I want to mock CreateTopicAsync method. But because of the sealed nature of the class i am not able to mock the class.
Any one Knows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you mock a Sealed class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484/how-do-you-mock-a-sealed-class)

Comment: But where is the Answer. I cannot make Microsoft to change implementation. :(

Comment: @Ramankingdom, Don't mock what you do not own. instead abstract it away and mock the abstraction. provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mock a `sealed` class. Mocking relies on inheritence to build on the fly copies of the data. So trying to mock a `sealed` class is impossible.

### So what do I do?

What you can do is write a wrapper:

```
public class NamespaceManagerWrapper : INamespaceManagerWrapper 
{
   private NamespaceManager _instance;

   public NamespaceManagerWrapper(NamespaceManager instance)
   {
      _instance = instance;
   }

   public ConsumerGroupDescription CreateConsumerGroup(ConsumerGroupDescription description)
   {
       return _instace.CreateConsumerGroup(description);
   }

   etc....
}
```

interface for the mock

```
public interface INamespaceManagerWrapper
{
   ConsumerGroupDescription CreateConsumerGroup(ConsumerGroupDescription description);
   ....etc.
}
```

your method should now accept your wrapper interface on the original object:

```
public void myMethod(INamespaceManagerWrapper mockableObj)
{
   ...
   mockableObj.CreateConsumerGroup(description);
   ...
}
```

Now you can mock the interface:

```
Mock<INamespaceManagerWrapper> namespaceManager = new Mock<INamespaceManagerWrapper>();
....etc.

myObj.myMethod(namespaceManager.Object);
```

Unfortunatly that's the best you can do. It's a siliar implementation to [HttpContextWrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper(v=vs.110).aspx)