# Override non-virtual string property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to unit test a method where a property is non-virtual, and there are two layers of inheritance - therefore I can not create a mock. I've created a fake, however for some reason the property value is still empty.

```
public class Cart {
    public string Currency { get; set; } // I'm trying to override this
}

// My fake class
public class CartFake : Cart
{
    public new string Currency {  // This should hide SomeBaseBase.Cart.Currency - but it does not
        get { return "USD"; }
        set { value = "USD"; }
    }
}


public abstract class SomeBaseBase {
    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
}

public class Base : SomeBaseBase {
   public string OtherProperties { get; set; }
}

// class under test
public class SomeClassFake : Base {
    public override Cart Cart => new CartFake();


    // Then when test is running I have this
    var currency = Cart.Currency // returns "" - when debugging I see two "Currency" properties and currency gets populated with ""
}
```

For some reason when the test is running I see two Currency properties and var currency = gets currency "" instead of "USD"

why is that? how can I make it so that USD is populated?

EDIT:

```
public class CartFake : Cart
{
    public CartFake() : base()
    {
        Currency = "USD";
    }
}
```

For some reason line: Cart.Currency is still empty :(

Comment: It sounds like you should revise what the `new` modifier means, basically. You are indeed *hiding* `Cart.Currency` from the perspective of a compile-time type of `CartFake`, but you're not *overriding* it, so when you refer to `Cart.Currency` in `var currency = Cart.Currency;` that doesn't know anything about `FakeCart`.

Comment: The problem is that Cart is a 3rd party library, I can not modify it. Is there any way around this? I've tried setting Currency (pls see EDIT), but var currency still gets ""

Comment: This might be useful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484/how-do-you-mock-a-sealed-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how shadowing or hiding works i.e. (using `new` keyword with members of class), if you are expecting that holding derived class (`CartFake`) reference as base class (`Cart`) would give you access to the value of property of derived class (`CartFake`), you are wrong.

That would have happened if you had the property defined `virtual` in base class (`Cart`) and you had overriden it using `override` keyword in derived class (`CartFake`), but that is not the case.

For the behavior that you are expecting for that your code needs to be like:

```
public class Cart {
    public virtual string Currency { get; set; } // I'm trying to override this
}

// My fake class
public class CartFake : Cart
{
    public override string Currency {  // This should hide SomeBaseBase.Cart.Currency - but it does not
        get { return "USD"; }
        set { value = "USD"; }
    }
}
```

now when you access the property `Currency` using variable of type base class but object is actually of type Derived class, you will get **USD** back.

When you are accessing the `Currency` property using reference of type `Cart` it is hiding the property `Currency` defined in the `CartFake`.

You need to cast it back to `CartFake`, if you want to get **USD** as result of `Currency` like:

```
// class under test
public class SomeClassFake : Base {
    public override Cart cart => new CartFake();


    // Then when test is running I have this
    var cartFake = cart as CartFake;
    var currency = cartFake.Currency // will return USD 
}
```

Refer to the question [Difference between Shadowing and Overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c) for more clarity.

Comment: that's the thing.. Currency in Cart is non-virtual and I can not modify 3rd party library

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `Cart` to the `CartFake` object who's property you want to return

```
var currency = ((CartFake)Cart).Currency;
```

Comment: no, that won't work. I can NOT modify Base class. I only created SomeClassFake for Unit testing purposes