# Mock PeriodicTimer for UnitTests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await, .net-6.0

My class is using [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-6.0) . I want to mock its time in unit tests. Is it possible?
I can set up the class to have a shorter period but that's not the best practice for unit testing.

Nsubstitute example is preferable, but does not really matter.

Maybe it's possible to make a wrapper, however, *ValueTask* is a bit more tricky. Maybe I need to dig into *IValueTaskSource*. But maybe someone has a solution?

The code I want to test:

```
public class Example : BackgroundService
     {
         private readonly PeriodicTimer _timer;
     
         public Example(IConfiguration configuration)
         {
             _timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.Parse(configuration["Interval"]));
         }
         
         protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
         {
             while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken)) // I want to simulate this without waiting for real time
             {
                 // Do something
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: What does your class look like and which part do you want to unit-test? Show some code instead of only explaining the situation, please.

Comment: Since it is a `sealed` class, it can't be mocked. See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484/how-do-you-mock-a-sealed-class)

Comment: You are on track thinking about a wrapper. A Mock for the wrapper then should have no problem returning a ValueTask.

Comment: @ewerspej Hi, I added an example

Comment: Yes, thank you. However, you already received a viable answer so I don't have anything to add right now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wrapper is the way to go, and it should be a dependency for your class.

Given these types

```
public interface IPeriodicTimer : IDisposable
{
    ValueTask<bool> WaitForNextTickAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public sealed class StandardPeriodicTimer : IPeriodicTimer
{
    private PeriodicTimer _actualTimer;

    public StandardPeriodicTimer(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        => _actualTimer = new PeriodicTimer(timeSpan);

    public async ValueTask<bool> WaitForNextTickAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => await _actualTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync(cancellationToken);


    public void Dispose() => _actualTimer.Dispose();
}

public class YourDependentClass
{
    public YourDependentClass(IPeriodicTimer timer) => _timer = timer;
    ...
}
```

You can initialize a `YourDependentClass` via `new`ing it up, or via dependency injection in production code.

```
var dependent = new YourDependentClass(new StandardPeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
```

To support the tests, you can create a stub that simply returns `true` every time without any delay between.

```
public sealed class TestPeriodicTimer : IPeriodicTimer
{
    public async ValueTask<bool> WaitForNextTickAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => await Task.FromResult(true);

    public void Dispose()
    {}
}
```

When you use this stub, we're assuming that somehow the timer stops based on some internal condition in the dependent class.

```
[Test]
public void TestTheDependentClass()
{
    // arrange
    var timer = new TestPeriodicTimer();
    var dependent = new YourDependentClass(timer);

    // act
    dependent.DoSomething();

    // assert
    // method exits because timer loop is done, timer disposed, etc.
    ...
}
```

Now, it could get a little trickier if you want the timer to fire a certain number of times, and to run assertions for each tick of the timer. You can either switch from a stub to NSubstitute as you suggest, or carry your stub a step further in its implementation.

But, it gets trickier still. The assertions should be about the state of the dependent *after* the dependent gets a return value for `WaitForNextTickAsync`. That means

- upon the very first call to `WaitForNextTickAsync` you do nothing
- on all subsequent calls but the final one you do assertions *after* the state changes
- and finally, you have to do assertions when the timer is disposed

I'll make this make sense.

The typical periodic timer is called in a loop. Let's say you call a method on your dependent that has this loop.

```
while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    // some work
    ...
}
```

Furthermore, let's say in your test code you want to assert on the state of the dependency *after* each time `// some work` happens, not before.

And finally, the test run has to be finite. That means it must run a certain number of times, or the dependent must somehow exit the loop early. Let's code for the former problem.

```
public sealed class TestPeriodicTimer : IPeriodicTimer
{
    private readonly int _numberOfExpectedTicks;
    private int _tickNumber;

    // our list of assertions...
    // we assert for tick 1 on the second call to WaitForNextTickAsync
    // we assert for tick 2 on the third call to WaitForNextTickAsync
    // etc.
    // so let's emulate a list that "starts" at index 2 instead of 0 to
    // avoid some confusing code later
    private readonly List<Action<int, bool>> _assertions = new() { null, null };

    public TestPeriodicTimer(int numberOfTicks) => _numberOfExpectedTicks = numberofTicks.

    // this is how we know what to assert when...
    public void AddAssertionsCallback(Action<int, bool> action)
        => _actions.Add(action);

    public async ValueTask<bool> WaitForNextTickAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // get result for current tick
        var result = await Task.FromResult(_numberOfExpectedTicks == ++_tickNumber);
        
        if (_tickNumber != 1)
        {
            // assert for the prior tick
            var assertedTickNumber = _tickNumber - 1;
            _assertions[_tickNumber](_assertedTickNumber, result);
        }
          return result;
    }    

    public void Dispose()
    {
       if (_disposed) return;
       _disposed = true;

        // assert for the final tick
        _assertions[_tickNumber + 1](_tickNumber, result);
    }

    private bool _disposed;
}
```

Ok, now we can finally code an expressive test.

```
[Test]
public void TestThreeTicksOfTheTimerInYourDependentClass()
{
    // arrange
    var timer = new TestPeriodicTimer(3);
    var dependent = new YourDependentClass(timer);

    dependent.AddAssertionsCallback((tickNumber, isFinalTick) =>
    {
        // assertions you expect to be true for tick 1 (actually
        // the second call to WatiForNextTickAsync)
        ...
        // and just to make sure...
        Assert.IsTrue(tickNumber, 1);
        Assert.IsFalse(isFinalTick);
    });

    dependent.AddAssertionsCallback((tickNumber, isFinalTick) =>
    {
        // assertions you expect to be true for tick 2 (actually
        // the third call to WatiForNextTickAsync)
        ...
        // and just to make sure...
        Assert.IsTrue(tickNumber, 2);
        Assert.IsFalse(isFinalTick);
    });

    dependent.AddAssertionsCallback((tickNumber, isFinalTick) =>
    {
        // assertions you expect to be true for tick 3 (actually
        // the call to Dispose(), because Dispose() happens after
        // tick 3's work
        ...
        // and just to make sure...
        Assert.IsTrue(tickNumber, 3);
        Assert.IsTrue(isFinalTick);
    });

    // act
    dependent.DoSomething();
    timer.Dispose();

    // assert
    // place any final assertions here as usual
}
```

This test says I want exactly 3 ticks to occur with the final (third) tick to of course be the last.

Wow. that was a lot of work. But this gives you a way to

- not sleep/block during a test
- test assertions for each and every tick if desired

A further improvement would be to share assertions across ticks, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like a good solution. Sadly the timer itself is not directly mockable :(

Comment: Ya. It's not uncommon to wrap non-mockable things though. Another example is creating an `INowProvider` to be able to fake a `DateTime.Now` for time-dependent tests, which can be important for testing, for example, a month-end process and so on.

Comment: I do not know if I someting missing, but I think that this line `var result = await Task.FromResult(_numberOfExpectedTicks == ++_tickNumber);` has wrong comparasion because in the first time this returns `false`. I think there should be sometinhg like `_numberOfExpectedTicks <= ++_tickNumber`. Or I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Kit's answer, I have created a Mock PeriodicTimer that allows the test to invoke the next tick when it wants and imho makes the test read more naturally.

I will post a more advanced answer also.

As with Kit's answer, you'll need the interface `IPeriodicTimer` and wrapper `StandardPeriodicTimer`.

Note that you need to inject `Func<TimeSpan, IPeriodicTimer> periodicTimerFactory` so that periodic timers can be created in your consumer class.

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly Func<TimeSpan, IPeriodicTimer> _periodicTimerFactory;

    public MyService(Func<TimeSpan, IPeriodicTimer> periodicTimerFactory)
    {
        _periodicTimerFactory = periodicTimerFactory;
    }

    public async Task Execute()
    {
        using var timer = _periodicTimerFactory(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {
            NumberOfExecutions++;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
        }
    }

    public int NumberOfExecutions { get; private set; } = 0;
}
```

My preferred way to create a mock is by using the neat Mock Builders pattern. This allows a mock to be created, configured and interacted with through a nice wrapper. This is what mine looks like.

```
using FakeItEasy;

namespace StackOverflow74867695.PeriodicTimer;

public class PeriodicTimerBuilder
{
    private readonly IPeriodicTimer _mock = A.Fake<IPeriodicTimer>(_ => _.Strict());
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _isWaitingForTick = new(0, 1);
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool>? _taskCompletionSource;
    public IPeriodicTimer Build()
    {
        A.CallTo(() => _mock.WaitForNextTickAsync(A<CancellationToken>._)).ReturnsLazily(GetNextTickTask);
        A.CallTo(() => _mock.Dispose()).DoesNothing();
        return _mock;
    }

    private ValueTask<bool> GetNextTickTask()
    {
        if (_taskCompletionSource is not null)
            _taskCompletionSource.SetException(new Exception("This is a testing exception from PeriodicTimerBuilder. WaitForNextTickAsync has been called before the previous Task has returned."));

        _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        
        _isWaitingForTick.Release();

        return new ValueTask<bool>(_taskCompletionSource.Task);
    }
    
    public void TriggerNextTick(bool hasFinished = false)
    {
        if (_taskCompletionSource is null)
            throw new Exception("This is a testing exception from PeriodicTimerBuilder: Next tick has been triggered before anything is awaiting it");

        _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(!hasFinished);
        _taskCompletionSource = null;
    }

     public async Task WaitUntilNextTickRequested(TimeSpan? timeout = null)
     {
         var timedOut = !await _isWaitingForTick.WaitAsync(timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
         if (timedOut) 
             throw new Exception("This is a testing exception from PeriodicTimerBuilder: Waiting for the next tick timed out. Ensure sufficient time is allowed for the processing to complete.");
     }
}
```

By wrapping this complexity, the unit test can now look like this

```
using Xunit;
using Assert = Xunit.Assert;

namespace StackOverflow74867695.PeriodicTimer;

public class MyServiceTests
{
    [Xunit.Theory]
    [InlineData(0)]
    [InlineData(1)]
    [InlineData(2)]
    [InlineData(100)]
    public async Task GivenMyService_WhenTimerTicksNTimes_ThenTaskExecutedNTimes(int n)
    {
        // ARRANGE
        var periodicTimer = new PeriodicTimerBuilder();
        var myService = new MyService(timespan => periodicTimer.Build());
        var executionTask = myService.Execute();
        await periodicTimer.WaitUntilNextTickRequested();            

        // ACT
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            // Setup other conditions here

            // Trigger the tick and then wait for it to finish
            periodicTimer.TriggerNextTick();
            await periodicTimer.WaitUntilNextTickRequested();

            // Capture state here to assert below
            // (or assert here if feeling rebellious)
        }
        
        // ASSERT
        // Signal that the timer has finished
        periodicTimer.TriggerNextTick(true);
        // Ensure you await the SUT task to wait for it to complete and also so that any exceptions thrown are surfaced.
        await executionTask;

        Assert.Equal(n, myService.NumberOfExecutions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon my previous answer, a situation I would recommend the unit test detects is when the Task is still awaiting a tick from the timer when the unit test has finished.

To avoid this, we can expand the PeriodicTimerBuilder so that it is disposed at the end of the test and it checks for this scenario. See the `Dispose` method at the end.

We also need the WaitForNextTickAsync task to be cancellable.

```cs
    public class PeriodicTimerBuilder : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IPeriodicTimer _mock = A.Fake<IPeriodicTimer>(_ => _.Strict());
        private readonly SemaphoreSlim _isWaitingForTick = new(0, 1);
        private TaskCompletionSource<bool>? _taskCompletionSource;
        private TimeSpan? _period;

        public IPeriodicTimer Build()
        {
            A.CallTo(() => _mock.WaitForNextTickAsync(A<CancellationToken>._)).ReturnsLazily((CancellationToken cancellationToken) => GetNextTickTask(cancellationToken));
            A.CallTo(() => _mock.Dispose()).DoesNothing();
            return _mock;
        }

        private async ValueTask<bool> GetNextTickTask(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (_taskCompletionSource is not null)
                _taskCompletionSource.SetException(new Exception("This is a testing exception from PeriodicTimerBuilder. WaitForNextTickAsync has been called before the previous Task has returned."));

            _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            
            _isWaitingForTick.Release();

            // Either the task awaiting the tick will be signalled by the _taskCompletionSource or the cancellationToken will signal we've been cancelled. See extension method at the end of the answer
            return await _taskCompletionSource.Task.OrCancelledBy(cancellationToken);
        }
        
        public void TriggerNextTick(bool hasFinished = false)
        {
            if (_taskCompletionSource is null)
                throw new Exception("This is a testing exception from PeriodicTimerBuilder: Next tick has been triggered before anything is awaiting it");

            _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(!hasFinished);
            _taskCompletionSource = null;
        }

        public PeriodicTimerBuilder WherePeriodIs(TimeSpan period)
        {
            _period = period;
            return this;
        }
        
        public async Task WaitUntilNextTickRequested(TimeSpan? timeout = null)
        {
            // A default timeout is provided as a fail safe in case another tick is never requested.
            var timedOut = !await _isWaitingForTick.WaitAsync(timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            if (timedOut) 
                 throw new Exception("This is a testing exception from PeriodicTimerBuilder: Waiting for the next tick timed out. Ensure sufficient time is allowed for the processing to complete.");
        }

        public void AssertPeriodSetWas(TimeSpan expected)
        {
            if (_period is null)
                throw new Exception($"In order to Assert the Period, ensure a call is made to {nameof(WherePeriodIs)}");
            
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, _period);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_taskCompletionSource is not null)
            {
                var exception = new Exception($"This is a testing exception from PeriodicTimerBuilder: The consumer was left awaiting WaitForNextTickAsync. Ensure {nameof(TriggerNextTick)} is called when appropriate to signal that the timer has finished.");
                _taskCompletionSource.SetException(exception); // Abort the awaited task
                throw exception; // Fail the unit test
            }
        }
    }
```

Whether you want to throw the exception to abort the awaiting task or signal that the timer has finished (which could execute more code unexpectedly), I'll leave to the reader.

I've also added a way to assert the period that was requested.

```cs
        // This test demonstrates the PeriodicTimerBuilder detecting that the consumer Task is still waiting, and throws - failing the test.
        [Fact]
        public async Task GivenMyService_WhenExecuted_ThenPeriodTimerSetFor1Min()
        {
            // ARRANGE
            // Note that the PeriodicTimerBuilder is now disposed at the end of the test
            using var periodicTimer = new PeriodicTimerBuilder();

            // In our func, we can now capture the period that was requested to assert later
            var myService = new MyService(timespan => periodicTimer
                .WherePeriodIs(timespan)
                .Build());
            
            // ACT
            var executionTask = myService.Execute();
            await periodicTimer.WaitUntilNextTickRequested();
            
            // ASSERT
            periodicTimer.AssertPeriodSetWas(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            // I have deliberated NOT signalled that the timer is finished here. This will be detected by the PeriodicTimerBuilder and the test will fail. To rectify, ensure the timer signals that it has finished at the end of the test.
            // Additional: don't forget to also await the executionTask afterwards. Note: Doing so without signalling that the timer has ended will lead to deadlock.
        }
```

Here's the aforementioned extension method for "adding" a cancellation token to a task.

```cs
       public static class TaskExtensions
       {
           public static async Task<TResult> OrCancelledBy<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
           {
               async Task<TResult> WaitUntilCancelled(CancellationToken ct)
               {
                   await Task.Delay(-1, ct); // Wait forever until cancellation
                   return default!;
               }

               return await await Task.WhenAny(task, WaitUntilCancelled(cancellationToken));
           }
}
```